# How to get the SonarQube analysis result of the development branch

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 7.9 version.
I have 100 issues generated after the master branch analysis.
I have created a develop branch from the master branch and have performed the analysis, now I see the issues are getting reported for the changes which are done as part of the particular commit.
As developers from my team dont have the access for master branch, I want the develop branch analysis to show all the 100 issues which are still existing in master branch.

Is there any way to do so? am using azure devops sonar extension to perform the analysis

Comment: Are you using SonarQube developer version?

Comment: We are using Enterprise version @Tony Yip